# Audacity, вместо звука воспроизводится шипение и треск

Tags: linux, аудио

В программе для редактирования звука во время проигрывания вместо звука идёт громкое шипение и треск и время идёт намного быстрее, как на перемотке.
OS Linux 32x

Comment: А причем здесь c++ ? а вот ось - более интересно. Если под линуксом и Audacity решил использовать аппартное воспроизведение звука (а большинство звуковых умеет aac воспроизводить), то может быть шум-треск.

Comment: @KoVadim, Linux 32x

Comment: Вы уверены, что файл точно не битый? Версии ещё выложите и audacity, и откуда получена, и версию системы.

Comment: @FeroxTL, это при воспроизведении любого звука, версия Audacity 2.0.6

Comment: @KoVadim программа на c++

Comment: П-Ш-Ш-Ш-Ш-аудио, не?
(перевожу - pulseaudio случайно не при делах?)

Comment: @gbg и на pulse и на default треск и шипение

Comment: а вообще звук работает? плееры работают?

Comment: @gbg воспроизводит только на default и pulse

Comment: @gbg "воспроизводит" - всмысле треск и шипение

Comment: @MihailRis так вот, открою страшную тайну - pulse - это и есть PulseAudio. Сносите его нафиг или обновляйтесь.

Comment: @KoVadim да, простые аудиоплееры работают нормально

Comment: @gbg это я понял, но есть другие способы? Просто раньше такого не было

Comment: @MihailRis - дискретизацию можно угадать попробовать. Поиграйтесь с переключателем частоты проекта в левом нижнем углу.

Comment: @gbg, дополнительно: иногда в некоторых моментах не надолго начинает проигрывать нормально

Comment: Сегодня аналогичную проблему на пульсе (в игре FTL) решил установкой latency в переменной среды на <100, например на 60. Детали могу написать чуть позже.

Comment: @D-side, интересно

Comment: @D-side, и каков же метод? Если он может сработать пишите его как ответ. Если сработает, отмечу ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Аналогичная проблема воспроизводится не только в Audacity, но и в *FTL Faster Than Light* под Linux при использовании Pulseaudio. Причём не всегда, но часто.

Эксперименты показали, что если запустить требуемую программу, предварительно задав переменную среды `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC` на `60`, то симптомы исчезают.

— [Источник](https://m.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/3pp771/cannot_get_ftl_to_output_to_pulseaudio/cw8pdnt)

---

**Disclaimer:** я понятия не имею, сработает ли это у вас, и если да, то почему. Но симптомы очень похожи: вместо звука треск и шум, в которых слабо слышен исходный звук на увеличенной скорости. Вполне вероятно, что лечится так же.

Comment: Где она задаётся?

Comment: А, всё понял, просто PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 audacity, теперь всё работает нормально))

Comment: В терминале нужно написать `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 audacity` если нужно открыть программу audacity, если lmms логично: `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 lmms` благодарен D-side за ответ, его я принимаю и даже в знак благодарности голосую за него)))

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, по-русски объяснить: что нужно нужно сделать, чтобы звук нормально воспроизводился в этой программе? Слова "переменная среда", "терминал" мне ни о чём не говорят. Мне просто нужно два файла(звука) соединить, а программа вместо аудио воспроизводит какой-то сплошной шум.